# Get File name and Download large file using Webclient Spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-webflux

How do we fetch the file name from the content-disposition and also support downloading large file(without using memory) when working with webclient spring boot (kotlin)

```
   suspend fun downloadFile(
        dir: String
    ) {
        val finalCookie = getCookie()
        try {

            val dirPath = Paths.get(dir)
            if (!Files.exists(dirPath)) {
                Files.createDirectories(dirPath)
            }
            val response = webClient.
            get()
                .uri { uriBuilder: UriBuilder ->
                    UriComponentsBuilder.fromUri(uriBuilder.build())
                        .path("/download/file")
                        .encode()
                        .build(false)
                        .toUri()
                }
                .header(HttpHeaders.COOKIE, finalCookie)
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToFlux(DataBuffer::class.java)

            // How to extract the file name from the response?
            var filename = "./output"
            val destination = Paths.get(dir, filename)
            // Need to use Databuffer so that no memory is used
            DataBufferUtils.write(response, destination).block()
            println("Downloaded $destination")
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            println("Error in downloading file: $e")
        }
    }
```

Tried above but it can only download the file with manually set file name.

Comment: I was able to grab the fileName using the onstatus method... ```
            val response = webClient.
            get()
                .uri { 
                }
                .retrieve()
                .onStatus(HttpStatus::is2xxSuccessful) { clientResponse ->
                    clientResponse.headers().asHttpHeaders().contentDisposition.filename?.let {
                        fileName = it
                    }
                    Mono.empty()
                }
                .bodyToFlux(DataBuffer::class.java)
```